# Create multiple rows in table from array?

Tags: javascript, orm, sequelize.js

Is possible to add multiple rows at once from array with sequelize.js? This is my code:

```
  var user = User.build({
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    userlevel: '3',
  });

  User
  .find({ where: { email: req.body.email } })
  .then(function(existingUser){

    if (existingUser) {
      return res.redirect('/staff');
    }

    user
    .save()
    .complete(function(err){
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.redirect('/staff');
    });
  }).catch(function(err){
    return next(err);
  });
```

Thanks for any advise!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/docs/instances/#working-in-bulk-creating-updating-and-destroying-multiple-rows-at-once

```
User.bulkCreate([{ /*  record one */ }, { /* record two */ }.. ])
```

Comment: Thanks. The link is old. A newer one is https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-bulkCreate

Comment: Manual has been updated. Here is a link to new version: https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/instances.html#working-in-bulk--creating--updating-and-destroying-multiple-rows-at-once-

Answer (score 0):

There has been an update in the document. check this link

https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/instances.html#working-in-bulk--creating--updating-and-destroying-multiple-rows-at-once-

```
User.bulkCreate([
  { username: 'barfooz', isAdmin: true },
  { username: 'foo', isAdmin: true },
  { username: 'bar', isAdmin: false }
])
```