# Waiting for all promises to succeed

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, express, promise, sequelize.js

I’m persisting entities to a postgres database using sequelize/nodejs/express/react

I have two main models, Countries and Activities, I’m working with the app and there’s a button called Save to database

When saving to database, I want to save all countries and once finished I want to start saving Activities.

Suppose I have 1000 Countries, do I have to create a promise for each country, and then use Promise.All with the array of those 1000 country promises in order to start saving Activities?

Is there any other way?, it could be many countries

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Comment: Are you looking for [Create multiple rows in table from array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27014849/1048572)?

Comment: It could be useful, I'll try it, thank you

Comment: share your tried code

Answer (score 0):

```
    db.TableName.bulkCreate([
      {
        profileId: 'profileId1',
        orgId: '102',
        userId: '100'
      },
      {
        profileId: 'profileId1',
        orgId: '102',
        userId: '100'
      },
      {
        profileId: 'profileId1',
        orgId: '102',
        userId: '100'
      },

    ])
    .then(resp => {
     ...
    });
```